# Passing parameters to directive AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

So i am new in AngularJS so dont judge so i have two buttons

```html
 <button type="button" class ="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Add First List</button>
    <button type="button" class ="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Second List</button>
```

wich open modal in directive and i have two instance on directive this..

```html
<div my-div-table  type="modal" directivevarible="ctrl.FirstList" datasource="ctrl.tempList" ></div>
    <div my-div-table  type="modal" directivevarible="ctrl.SecondList" datasource="ctrl.tempList" ></div>
```

so i want when i click first button to take first 2 variables when i click second button i want to take second 2 variables ..and that is my directive

```js
app.directive('myDivTable',function () {
    
    var controller = ['$scope',function ($scope) {
            $scope.AddTempElem =function () {
                $scope.datasource.push({startDate: $scope.start, endDate: $scope.end, workInHours: $scope.hours});
            }
            $scope.Submit = function () {
                $scope.directivevarible = $scope.directivevarible.concat( $scope.datasource);
                $scope.datasource = [];
            }
            
        }],
        template=function (tElem,tAtrrs) {
            if(tAtrrs.type ==='table'){
                return 'template.html';
            }
            if(tAtrrs.type ==='modal'){
                return 'modal.html';
            }
            
        }
    return{
        scope:{
            datasource:'=',
            directivevarible:'='
        },
        controller:controller,
        templateUrl:template
    };
});
```

Please help?

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap.

Comment: Its take me 1 day to understand bootstrap.js a little and to write one simple modal..so any change with bootstrap

Comment: Learning to use it in an angular app while learning to use angular is just a bad idea. You already have a complicated issue with the 2 buttons and that problem is very easily managed using an integrated angular module that is designed for what you need

Comment: i did it ... :V :V Thanks